# how to push nested array in one array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

how to join data based on sort in nested object of array
I have data object like this:

```
{
  "data": [
     {
        "id": "1",
     },
     {
        "id": "2",
     },
 ],
 "includes": {
     "users": [
         {
            "name": "Ronni Herdi"
         },
         {
            "name": "Floridamaya2"
         },
  
    ],
    "tweets": [
          {
             "created_at": "2021-02-26T01:08:42.000Z"
          },
         {
             "created_at": "2021-02-26T01:46:27.000Z"
         }
    ]
  }
}
```

how to join data based on sorting make data array in one array, i want result like this:

```
{
    "data": [
         {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Ronni Herdi",
            "created_at": "2021-02-26T01:08:42.000Z"
         },
         {
           "id": "2",
           "name": "Floridamaya2",
           "created_at": "2021-02-26T01:46:27.000Z"
         }
    ]
}
```

how can i do that...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply loop over the data and append items to a new associative array:

```
$input_json = ''; // json from post

$input = json_decode($input_json, true);

$joined = [];
foreach($input['data'] as $i => $item) {
  $joined[] = array_merge(
     $item, 
     $input['includes']['users'][$i], 
     $input['includes']['tweets'][$i]
  );
}
$output = ['data' => $joined];
print_r($output);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/feb743acd25f4dfa9674d18b74d9d2a5d6b6a78f